# JsHint, can I target all unused parameters in a function definition instead of just last?

Tags: javascript, jshint

This is more a sanity check idea.  Currently unused:true only makes sure the last function parameter is used, but sometimes I want to make sure that I'm using what everything passed in.  Is there an override to make see all unused function parameters?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have changed between version 1.0.0 and version 1.1.0. The following code raises three warning with 1.0.0 but only one with 1.1.0:

```
/*jshint unused: true */
(function example(a, b, c) {
    /* Don't use any of the arguments */
}());
```

Looking at the JSHint source (in particular, [the `warnUsed` function](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/1.1.0/src/stable/jshint.js#L3463)) it appears that the `unused` option has gained some new functionality. You can now set it to 1 of 3 new values (it's set to `last-param` by default):

```
var warnable_types = {
    "vars": ["var"],
    "last-param": ["var", "last-param"],
    "strict": ["var", "param", "last-param"]
};
```

By setting it to `strict`, the above example will once again raise 3 warnings, 1 for each argument, instead of just 1 warning for the last argument:

```
/*jshint unused: strict */
(function example(a, b, c) {
    /* Don't use any of the arguments */
}());
```